# updating postgres table with unique Integer array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not so good in queries. I have a table with column users which is of type 'users integer ARRAY'.
For e.g. it looks like users[1,2]

Now I want to update this array with new value, but it has to be distinct. For e.g. if I want to add 3 to it then the output should be users[1,2,3] and if I add 1 to it then it should not make any update.

My current query to update this column is:

```
UPDATE userTable SET users = array_append(users, 3) WHERE user_id=1
```

I am not getting how and where to define so it only takes the distinct users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't do the update if the value is present:

```
UPDATE userTable
    SET users = array_append(users, 3)
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND NOT users @> array[3];
```

Comment: What if initial 'users' array is empty? Because I tried this query with initially empty array, it did not update the table.

Comment: Hmmm . . . I imagine the problem is that there is nothing to append if the array is empty.  So, `users` doesn't change.

Comment: So what shall I do if I want to update the 'users' array for the first time?

Comment: @Ragu . . . It works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d7a2185c34ffb89123a22e2865464f9.

Comment: this is how I am creating and inserting in a table. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?  : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2695e7948fc285dd4aeb1cd7fa4a7238

Comment: @Ragu . . . Default the value to an empty array rather than `NULL`:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e421ea93966daaa3d9c79778c269010.